Why does `echo` interpret "\n" as new line character only in interactive shells and not when executing a shell script?
Why does echo interpret "\n" as new line character in interactive shells only and not when executing a shell script also?
Running in an interactive bash shell:
$ echo "hello\nworld"
hello
world

Running as a script using bash:
$ echo 'echo "hello\\nworld"' > hello_world.sh
$ bash hello_world.sh
hello\nworld

Running as a script using sh:
$ sh hello_world.sh
hello
world


https://superuser.com/questions/256465/echo-newline-character-not-working-in-bash (and your 2nd snippet probably does not create the file you really want to show - you overescaped a bit). Also I cannot reproduce your first snippet: for me running that command produces a single-line string with \n included verbatim. This is why echo -e (non-POSIX) exists - plain echo does not do that magic in bash, but does in sh. POSIX does not mandate any specific treatment of \n.

For reference, I'm on GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).

Please read why-is-printf-better-than-echo

By default, the external echo command does not interpret the escape character and prints its arguments verbatim.
The -e argument tells it to interpret the sequences that start with \ as special characters.
For speed optimisation, some shells provide internal implementations of echo and these implementations may support different arguments and may have different default values for them.
It is also possible that the initialisation script of sh (which is probably also executed by bash) defines a function or an alias named echo that delegates the work to the external or builtin echo with the extra argument -e.

Different versions of echo (or even the same version in different modes) behave differently. Some interpret escapes by default, some don't. Some you can tell to interpret escapes with -e, some will print "-e" as part of their output. It's a complete nightmare; I once had a bunch of my scripts break because an OS update changed bash's default behavior. If you want consistent behavior, use printf (with an appropriate format string) instead of echo for anything involving escapes and/or command options.

TLDR: interactive bash has a shell built-in echo different from /usr/bin/echo

The utility which can be used to show that echo in an interactive bash command line is actually using the shell built-in echo command, rather than /usr/bin/echo.
Since they behave differently regarding their interpretation of escape sequences, the output differs accordingly.
$ which -a echo
echo: shell built-in command
/usr/bin/echo
/bin/echo

/usr/bin/sh is pointing to /usr/bin/dash which does not have a shell built-in for echo and uses /usr/bin/echo instead, so this explains the difference in behavior when running the script using sh over bash.
$ which -a echo
/usr/bin/echo
/bin/echo


which is the wrong tool. You can use dash -c 'type echo' to see that echo is a shell builtin. In fact, which is not a builtin for bash, so perhaps that first output is from zsh?

You claim to be running Bash in both instances. Maybe that wasn't actually true, though?
